# Let $|a|=4$ and $|b|=2$ be in group $G$ with $a^3b=ba$. Find $|ab|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $|a|=4$ and $|b|=2$ be in group $G$ with $a^3b=ba$. Find $|ab|$.

Are those absolute values? Or something else?

Comment: These likely refer to the order of the elements. That is, $a^4 = 1$ and $a^k \ne 1$ for any $0 < k < 4$.

Comment: Could it be as simple as $|a|*|b|=|ab|$?

Comment: It might be, it might not be. In general, in a non-abelian group (of which this is an example), there's not much relation between $|ab|$ and $|a|$, $|b|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are orders of elements.

The order of an element $g\in G$, denoted $|g|$, is defined as the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $g^n = e$, the identity element of the group.

So, in your question, we know that $a^4 = e$ (and no smaller power will do), and that $b^2 = e$ (and no smaller power will do).

This is enough to conclude that $|ab| = 2$, because $(ab)^2 = abab = a(ba)b = a(a^3b)b = a^4b^2 = e\cdot e = e$, and $ab$ cannot be the identity, because otherwise a would be the inverse of b, and so have the same order.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint, start taking powers of $ab$. First note that if

$$ab = e \implies a = b^{-1} \implies a^2 = 2$$

contradicting that $|a| = 2$. Next we have

$$(ab)^2 = abab = a(a^3b)b = a^4 b^2 = ...?$$